# How can a root controller call methods in its child controller and vice versa?

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

I have 2 view controllers.

```
Root -> (modal) -> Child
```

The root has timers and stuff.  When the timer goes out *and* the child controller is in view, I want my root controller call a method on the Child Controller.

Also, when the Child Controller is in view and the user pushes a button, I want it to call a method in the root controller.

What's the best way to do this without causing memory problems? Notifications? Should I set a reference to the child controller and vice versa?

Comment: "Memory" is not involved in the story. There are no "memory problems". Either the two view controllers exist simultaneously or they do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose to have 2 view controllers like these:

```
TIMEXMainViewController *mainViewController = [TIMEXMainViewController new];

TIMEXChildViewController *childViewController = [TIMEXChildViewController new];
```

In `TIMEXMainViewController.m` in order to access the child:

```
TIMEXChildViewController *childViewController = (TIMEXChildViewController *)self.presentedViewController;
[childViewController publicMethod];
```

In `TIMEXChildViewController.m` in order to access the main:

```
TIMEXMainViewController *mainViewController = (TIMEXMainViewController *)self.presentingViewController;
[mainViewController publicMethod];
```

Of course remember to `#import "TIMEX(Main/Child)ViewController.h"` in your implementation files.

Answer (score 2):

They *have* references to each other. It all depends on the view controller hierarchy / architecture, but that hierarchy is always known and there is always a way to walk it from one view controller to another. It's just a matter of knowing your own architecture and studying the documentation on the UIViewController class and thinking about what it's telling you. In a modal presentation, for example, they are typically each other's `presentingViewController` and `presentedViewController`.

Comment: And see my book's discussion of this topic: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch13.html#_visibility_by_relationship

Comment: In my child, when I do ```self.presentedViewController.``` how come I don't see my public methods of my root?

Comment: `self.presentedViewController` returns a `UIViewController` – you need to typecast the result of that to whatever your root view controller's class is.